# Esper Tech Installation using Maven - No access on transport - Maybe jar issue?

Tags: maven, esper

I 've already read lot from your site, but it's the first time I really cannot find resolution for my problem through searching.

I try to install **Esper Tech** on **Windows 8.1** with help of **Maven 3.3**. After many problems, I have this one too. It seems like a ***dependency problem between 2 source setting files of Esper***.

Below my facts.

1.Maven's output (not all output but only for these 2 libraries)

```
 [INFO] ----------------
[INFO] Building Esper Examples TerminalSvc - MDB 1.0
[INFO] ----------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\etc
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [example-terminalsvc-mdb] in [C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target\example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [922 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target\example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ example-terminalsvc-mdb ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\target\example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0.war to C:\Users\marianna\.m2\repository\com\espertech\example-terminalsvc-mdb\1.0\example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\marianna\esper-master\examples\terminalsvc\terminalsvc-mdb\pom.xml to C:\Users\marianna\.m2\repository\com\espertech\example-terminalsvc-mdb\1.0\example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Esper Examples TerminalSvc - EAR 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/espertech/example-terminalsvc-mdb/1.0/example-terminalsvc-mdb-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Esper .............................................. SUCCESS [02:52 min]
[INFO] EsperIO-AMQP ....................................... SUCCESS [ 16.781 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-CSV ........................................ SUCCESS [  6.984 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-DB ......................................... SUCCESS [  4.047 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-HTTP ....................................... SUCCESS [  6.438 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-Socket ..................................... SUCCESS [  3.078 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-SpringJMS .................................. SUCCESS [ 13.187 s]
[INFO] EsperIO-Stax ....................................... SUCCESS [  5.032 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.062 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - AutoID ............................ SUCCESS [  1.516 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - Benchmark ......................... SUCCESS [  2.015 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - CycleDetect ....................... SUCCESS [  1.485 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - MarketDataFeed .................... SUCCESS [  1.312 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - MatchMaker ........................ SUCCESS [  1.656 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - NamedWinQuery ..................... SUCCESS [  0.985 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - OHLCPlugInView .................... SUCCESS [  1.265 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - QualityOfServiceSLA ............... SUCCESS [  1.313 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - RFIDAssetZone ..................... SUCCESS [  2.297 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - RuntimeConfig ..................... SUCCESS [  1.062 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - ServerShell ....................... SUCCESS [  1.500 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples - StockTicker ....................... SUCCESS [  1.172 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Common ................ SUCCESS [  0.516 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Receiver .............. SUCCESS [  0.359 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Sender ................ SUCCESS [  0.625 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - MDB ................... SUCCESS [  4.547 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - EAR ................... FAILURE [  7.672 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Esper Examples - TerminalServiceJSE ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Esper Examples - Transaction ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Esper Examples - Trivia Geeks Club ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Esper .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-22T14:06:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/350M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example-terminalsvc-ear: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.espertech:example-terminalsvc-ear:ear:1.0: Could not transfer artifact com.espertech:example-terminalsvc-mdb:jar:1.0 from/to local-repository (~/.m2/repository): Cannot access ~/.m2/repository with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access ~/.m2/repository using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported transport protocol -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

2.My command for compilation is below: 
**mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip=true > log.txt**
*(gpg was my first big problem)*

3.pom.xml from last project 'Esper Examples TerminalSvc - EAR' for *dependency* part

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-terminalsvc-mdb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Steps I took to search issue:

1. rights on ./~m2/repository -> i made it public (not good tactic I know)
2. download manually .jar and paste it on target folder. But link has **404 error**!
3. I tried to figure out why .jar is not found after it's project compilation. But this compilation has as a result .**w**ar not .**j**ar

What could I miss?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the examples parent pom level (~/esper/examples/terminalsvc/) try to do

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

The project builds fine.

```
INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ esper-terminalsvc ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Common ................ SUCCESS [  9.449 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Client ................ SUCCESS [  0.298 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - Receiver .............. SUCCESS [  0.101 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - MDB ................... SUCCESS [  0.581 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc - EAR ................... SUCCESS [  0.811 s]
[INFO] Esper Examples TerminalSvc ......................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.382 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-23T13:29:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/229M
```

Update

Please edit the file /esper/examples/terminalsvc/terminalsvc-ear/pom.xml and add the line  war on the dependency, as shown below :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-terminalsvc-mdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried but it didn't work. Could you please share full command results? I will try to find out in which line is my problem. please try -X on Maven for full stack analysis. Thanks again!

Comment: 1. clone the github repository https://github.com/espertechinc/esper.git  2. cd to /<folder that you cloned the repository/examples/ 3. try the above command. it works

Comment: Hello, I tried this solution with esper-master too, but I have the same problem.. I understand that MDB is not compiled correctly. Could you please paste full output? I'll try to isolate problematic line. Thanks really for your help.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much, all it was needed it was just the <type>... I had tried to change pom.xml of terminal-mdb not ear... Really thanks!

Comment: happy to help! :) Actually this is a mistake on their code.